# Make 3d model from picture and calculate volume

Tags: qgis, volume, 3d-model

I have a picture (fictional) of a mountain. What I want and am not able to do without help, is to make the coordinates and height to the right scale.

I have a line that represents 10 km on the original picture and some height contours. I've made the colour picture into greyscale but now, when I try to make it a 3D model using Qgis2threejs, I doesn't work, I think because the file doesn't have a DEM layer. The Profile Tool Plugin does give the right shape, but not the correct heights.

At the end of this I want to be able to calculate volumes of (pieces of) the mountain above certain contours. And I need to make a 3d model of these parts of the mountain (maybe using qgis2threejs plugin)

Edit: sorry for not giving enough info, the greyscale was made by checking which style the first picture had and turning each colour separatly into a 32-greyscale using GIMP like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/978066/exchange-colors-to-grey-scale-height-map?newreg=81a2e51bb18347748c4fab9cbee7ffa9). The first picture is only an image, so .png, therefore the grayscale is also only a .png image.

The image is not geo-referenced because it is a fictional mountain, the only reference is the 10 km line in the colour image. The height contours are 50 m each with the 2,4 to 2,5 km contours defined as such. This is the only data I have, two pictures.

[image] [image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a "Focused question / Best answer" model, and this question isn't as focused on a specific issue as much as it is a general tasking order (without the data or enough useful information to actually solve it).  Please [edit] the question to detail the step(s) you used to make the greyscale image and what the range of values are, and where you were headed when you got stuck.

Comment: Is the image georeferenced ? Is the greyscale image made of polygons or is it a raster file ? What is the file format of your data ?

Comment: I edited the question, it's not georeferenced. The grey scale (I think) is a raster file, because I just dragged and dropped the .png onto Qgis. This given, the format of my data is .png I guess.